# MEAN application link redirection

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, redirect

I've setup a system where a user can login to a website I created with a MEAN application. It's a two step setup. The user registers an account and is then emailed a link where it redirects them to a "http://localhost:3000/users/verify?email=". My problem is when the user clicks the link, it redirects them to here in the server file called app.js

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

As opposed to redirecting them to

```
router.post('/verify', function(req, res){
```

In the /users.js file.

I know it doesn't sound the clearest, but I can further explain my problem if that helps. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks a link, it always issues a GET request, so your `app.get('*', ...)` matches, not your `router.post()`.  Also, important to note that the order declared matters so for example if you do both as gets but do it in this order:

```
app.get('*', ...);
app.get('/verify', ...);
```

the * route will still match first and probably end the request before '/verify' is hit.

Comment: Is there anyway to implement what I'm doing with a get request?

Comment: Yes, just change your router.post() to a router.get() and if it's in the correct order, you're set.